# What is '?-mix' in a Ruby Regular Expression

Tags: ruby, regex

Just trying to debug a regular expression in ruby. When I print the contents of a regular expression, it shows `?-mix` at the beginning of the regular expression even though those characters were not part of the expression. Please see the following IRB output to see this illustrated

```
irb(main):028:0* EXPR = /^a$/
=> /^a$/
irb(main):029:0> EXPR
=> /^a$/
irb(main):030:0> puts EXPR
(?-mix:^a$)
=> nil
```

As you can see, when you use `puts` to print out the contents of a regular expression, there is `?-mix` at the beginning. Should I be concerned by this? Where is it coming from?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

`mix` is not the English word *mix*, it's options of `Regexp`.

See [`Regexp#to_s`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Regexp.html#method-i-to_s):

> Returns a string containing the regular expression and its options (using the (`?opts:source`) notation.

In your example, `m` is for *multiline mode*, `i` is for *case insensitive*, and `x` is for *extended mode*. **Options before the dash are on, those after are off (default)**. The question's example, `?-mix`, has all options off.

You can turn them on like:

```
puts /^a$/mix
# =>(?mix:^a$)
```

Comment: great, thanks for that. That m option might be what's screwing up my reg ex. Just need to find out out to set it to single line instead

Comment: It might be worth noting that the `-` turns those options *off* (which they are by default, but you can switch them on and off for different sections of a regex, if your regex flavor supports that).

Comment: @Shantaram: Are you aware that Ruby's `(?m)` is the same as every other regex flavor's `(?s)` option? What are you expecting  `^`  and `$` to match?

Comment: So if those options are off by default which results in ?-mix, does that mean ?m-ix has multiline turned on? (I moved the m before the -)

Answer (score 18):

Regarding the `-` it's a syntax for flags. Those before the dash are on, and those after are off.

As expalined in the [Regexp docs](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Regexp.html#class-Regexp-label-Options), this is an inline modifier, using the `(?on-off)` syntax:

> The end delimiter for a regexp can be followed by one or more single-letter options which control how the pattern can match.
>
> - `/pat/i` - Ignore case
> - `/pat/m` - Treat a newline as a character matched by `.`
> - `/pat/x` - Ignore whitespace and comments in the pattern
> - `/pat/o` - Perform `#{}` interpolation only once
>
> `i`, `m,` and `x` can also be applied on the subexpression level with the `(?on-off)` construct, which enables options *on*, and disables options *off* for the expression enclosed by the parentheses.

Hence, in my case this means the options `m`, `i`, and `x` are off and none are on.