# Why is my line anchor not functioning as I expected?

Tags: regex, swift, icalendar, icu

I'm trying to parse the location entries from a .ics file as follows seen in the image below . Normally this works fine even though the only tester I can find is PCRE rather than ICU as I just need to add an extra backslash to any special characters.

However in swift I get the following results:

```
"^Location" //No Match
"^VERSION" //No Match
"^BEGIN" //Match
"^ :" //Match
```

Can I get the '^' anchors to function like they do in the PCRE tester?

**PCRE regex tester**
[image: PCRE regex tester]

**Code**

```
func testParticipantParsing()
{
    //let locationRegex = "^LOCATION:(.*(?:\\n :?.*)*)"
    let locationRegex = "LOCATION:(.*(?:\\n :?.*)*)"
    var regex : NSRegularExpression! = nil
    var resultsArray = [String]()

//Parse for location
    do
    {
        regex = try NSRegularExpression(pattern: locationRegex, options: NSRegularExpressionOptions.init(rawValue: 0))
        let nsString = content as NSString
        let results = regex.matchesInString(content, options: [], range: NSMakeRange(0, nsString.length))
        resultsArray = results.map{ nsString.substringWithRange($0.range) }
    }
    //Catch errors if regex fails
    catch
    {
        print("invalid regex")
    }
    //Strip .ics new line tokens
    for var result in resultsArray
    {
        result = result.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n :", withString: "")
        result = result.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("\n ", withString: "")
        print(result)
    }
}
```

Comment: Note that your regex does not deal with different case of `LOCATION`, parameters in that property, and the keyword `LOCATION` being split over multiple lines, all of which are valid things to do in iCalendar. You're better off using a real parser.

Comment: @Evert I'd like to but with swift 2 being relatively new I can't find anything; or at least not with the correct license. I may have misunderstood you but I think I've dealt with this with the line anchor as all instances were the user creates a new line themselves appear to have the separator ' :' appended to the beginning of the new line or ' ' if the line has occurred naturally as seen on the 11th line. I may have missed something do you think there are times when '\nLOCATION:' could appear together?

Comment: just to give you an example, this is also valid:   `lOcA\r\n\ttION;x-param=foo;x-param2="hello::":actualvalue\r\n`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the `(?m)` at the start of your pattern.

```
let locationRegex = "(?m)^LOCATION:(.*(?:\\n :?.*)*)"
                     ^^^^
```

The `(?m)` is the inline modifier version of the MULTILINE modifier that forces `^` to match the location at the beginning of a *line* rather than *string* (and makes `$` match the location at the end of the line, before the newline sequence).

See [Table 4: Flag Options](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/):

> **`m` flag:**
>   Control the behavior of `^` and `$` in a pattern. By default these will only match at the start and end, respectively, of the input text. If this flag is set, `^` and `$` will also match at the start and end of each line within the input text.

Comment: Perfect, I didn't know about these flags. Thanks.

Comment: Oh, there can be funnier situations with these inline modifiers, see [What is '?-mix' in a Ruby Regular Expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28630936/what-is-mix-in-a-ruby-regular-expression). It was not any "mix" :)